# Loading indicator for starting javaScript web-application

Tags: php, javascript, web-services, web-applications, nginx

How can i make something similar like GMail has http://o7.no/H72gPf
When application starting, gmail showing progress bar and it show us the percent (part) of loaded content already.

How i can mesure that certain JS file (HTML content, CSS or Images) loaded partially or fully ?

P.S. On server side I would like to use PHP

Comment: If you really need one, your page is probably too slow.  If you make one that is accurate (i.e. doesn't fake it), your page will probably be too complicated.

Comment: What about applications? Not everything done in a browser is just a website.

Comment: @KenThompson yep it's not usual web site. It would be web service, like web app

Comment: Whether the web site is "usual" or "unusual" doesn't change the fundamentals of how the browser works, which makes it difficult to include an **accurate** progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a number of ways.

An easy way is to place your script tags (for included scripts) below the content, and have each included script call some function defined in the HEAD section of your document.

So if you define this in a script tag in the head of your document:

```
function increment_progress() {
   // your HTML-dependent implementation here
}
```

Then just do this at the bottom of included scripts:

```
increment_progress();
```

What `increment_progress` does really depends on what your progress-bar looks like, and how you build it with HTML.

For example you could have a TABLE in a DIV, adding a TD to the first TABLE row each call to `increment_progress`, with fixed TD widths and different background colours for TD and DIV. You then choose a width for TD's which roughly equals (width of DIV) / (number of scripts to be loaded).

Something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #your_interface { display: none; }
    #progressbar { width: 100px; background: #00ff00; }
    #progressbar table { width: 100%; margin: 0px; }
    #progressbar table td { padding: 0px; border: 0px; 
                            border-collapse: collapse; 
                            background: #ff0000; width: 10px; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" href="/path/to/jquery"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    function increment_progress() {
       $('#progressbar table tr').eq(0).append('<td>&nbsp;</td>');
       count++;
       if (count == 9) { // the number of scripts loaded below
          $('#progressbar').hide();
          $('#your_interface').show();
       }
    }
  </script>
<head>
<body>
  <div id="progressbar"><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></div>

  <div id="your_interface">
     The rest of your content here!
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" href="/path/to/script1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" href="/path/to/script2"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" href="/path/to/script3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" href="/path/to/script4"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" href="/path/to/script5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" href="/path/to/script6"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" href="/path/to/script7"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" href="/path/to/script8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" href="/path/to/script9"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you've got a fast server and fast internet connection, you'll barely see it :-)

If you're already loading scripts using AJAX, you could call `increment_progress()` from your 'response' handler function.

**Update:** to show how to transition to the real user interface after loading.

Comment: Thanks for idea. it's good, but not enough for me. I would like to get next picture. Blank screen with loading indicator. Behind this (in hidden state) can keep loading all content, images, css, js, html ... and when everything downloaded and ready to use it become visible

Comment: actually this screen i would like to see only once all other request of my app will be made without reloading whole page

Comment: Add a conditional expression to increment_loader() to $('#your_interface').show() and $('#progressbar').hide(). Make both your interface and the loader positioned/styled how you want using CSS.

Comment: what condition I should use to detect that all hidden content is finished loading, and ready for use ? $(document).ready() ?

Comment: I've updated to give an example. Only use $().ready() if you really need to wait until the DOM is ready (i.e: images/etc have finished loading) -- if it's enough that your layout is ready, then just kick off your code from your included scripts directly (that's why I put the scripts _after_ the content).

Comment: will .ready() wait while new scripts will finished loading too ? by adding dynamically <script> tag?

Comment: No,.ready() waits until the DOM is "ready" to be touched by JavaScript. However, normally your JavaScript files will load in order, and any script blocks you execute source-wise after them will execute after, so you don't need .ready() to wait for script files.

Comment: The jQuery Ready (http://api.jquery.com/ready/) documentation does a god job at explaining what it and other page events wait for / respond to.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar just the other day, I needed to do some heavy querying while the user was waiting, what you could do is this:

Create a page with an iframe in it, the page inside the iframe starts a new thread that inits the application. After starting the thread it shows a page with a progress bar, it also has a simple script that reloads the page every x seconds. This can be as simple as this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.reload();
            }, 10000);
        </script>
        <img src="/images/loader.gif" />
    </body>
</html>
```

When the page reloads it first checks the status of the application and than send either a loading page again or a page that reloads the top frame to the actual application start screen.

I saved the status of the application in a simple file that was updated after every major action, it needed to be like this because it where separate threads. According to the status in this file you can adjust the loading bar to show.

Comment: window.location.reload makes every time new Http request ?